# Forced strictness for lists in haskell

Tags: haskell, data-structures, lazy-evaluation, evaluation, strictness

I made really time consuming algorithm which produces a short string as the result. When I try to print it (via putStrLn) it appears on the screen character by character. I did understand why that happened, and I tried to force evaluation of the string before actual printing.

```
myPrint !str = putStrLn str
```

But this help very little. When I ran the program in debug I noticed that the !str forced evaluation only for the first character.

Does anyone know why is that, and how to deal with this?

Comment: What is your problem with char-per-char printing? I like this approach, as you can see, when the program will evaluate your stuff.

Comment: This is gonna be a tool, it just looks a bit ugly. But for debugging purposes I completely agree, it might be useful.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`(!)` translates into `seq`, which evaluates strictly to [Weak Head Normal Form](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Graph_reduction#Weak_Head_Normal_Form) -- that is, it only evaluates to the outermost constructor. To evaluate more deeply, you need a "deep" form of `seq`.

This is known as `deepseq`.

It is in [the deepseq package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/deepseq/1.1.0.2/doc/html/Control-DeepSeq.html).

Comment: To clarify, for lists, the "outermost constructor" is the leftmost `:`, which explains why it forces only the first character of the string.

Comment: A bit netter illustration of what is Weak Head Normal Form is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness)

Answer (score 2):

```
seqList :: [a] -> ()
seqList [] = ()
seqList (x:xs) = strictList xs
```

Comment: This will sort of work, but only if you actually require the `()` to be evaluated, e.g. `seq (seqList xs) (doSomethingWith xs)`.  Even then, it will only force the spine of the list, not the individual elements (not that just forcing the spine isn't useful).  It can be tricky to get strictness correct!

Comment: Also, I think you mean `seqList` in the last line.

Comment: Another way is to perform some useless computations on the list: length $ filter (=="?") list.