# Strict functional language which can be compiled into native code

Tags: functional-programming

Recently I started looking at functional languages to make some algorithmic parts of my application more reliable. Of course I bumped into Haskell. But it prepared too many surprises  for me with its laziness. Sometimes simple things become very and very slow.

So I'm wondering is there a language I can use to write small algorithms in functional style but without unnecessary laziness which causes more problems then helps.

The program should be compiled into Win32/64 native code (preferably dll) and have comparable performance with C++.

Comment: do you know about bang patterns in haskell? http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/users_guide/bang-patterns.html

Comment: Yes, but I find it difficult to use. I tried to place them in different places to make application use less memory but still did not win. Usually the most problems I have with lists.

Comment: Indeed lists is something difficult to make strict in Haskell

Comment: @Maxym: bang patterns only evaluate to WHNF, no? I'd recommend deepseq when you really need strictness.

Comment: @amindfv yes, you are right. That's why it doesn't really work with lists

Comment: this was discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558043/forced-strictness-for-lists-in-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OCaml](http://ocaml.org/) is probably the closest to Haskell, but it's strict and impure. It's a successor to [ML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29).

OCaml, ML, and Haskell can all be compiled to machine code on any common platform.

In my experience, though, laziness is usually a great feature once you get a sense for how it works.

Comment: didn't look at that language yet. Does it integrate well with C++ code?

Comment: @Alexandr: O'Caml has an FFI, but I haven't used it.

Comment: I see that Wondows Distribution is for the port based on the MinGW toolchain. Will it work well if I'll try to link resulting library with Visual Studio binaries?

Comment: @Alexandr good question. I didn't use OCaml but I think that in the output library there will not be any classes, only functions. And for functions export it should be more or less compatible on binary level.

Comment: @amindfv, upvoting because now I've started thinking of learning a bit of OCaml too :)

Comment: I will hope it's easy to integrate, I'll try OCaml